# Replace all cells with specific combinations of words

Tags: r, rstudio

Have a df of 29000 rows and 189 columns. In some rows I have

```
    "true / Bob"
```

I want to find a way in which I can replace all these cells into

```
    "Bob"
```

Looking for a solution in which I don't just say replace "true / Bob" for "Bob". Tried to work with

```
gsub
lapply
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this to replace the characters

```
as.data.frame(lapply(df, function(v) gsub(".*Bob.*","Bob",v)))
```

Comment: Sorry, just to clarify, I'm looking for a function in which I just say replace all cells with "Bob" in it, to "Bob". Since I have a total of 100 combinations with "... / Bob" I cannot just type "true / Bob"

Comment: Then replace with `gsub(".* / Bob", "Bob", v)`

Comment: @blaugrana Do you mean replace all contents in the cell including "Bob" to just "Bob"?

Comment: @ThomasIsCoding, Yeah

Comment: I don't think that you need the grouping parentheses. `gsub(".* / Bob", "Bob", v)` should be sufficient (since you are not referring back to the group)

Comment: And if your cells aren't all in the format of `... / Bob` but **any** format including Bob, then use `.*Bob.*` instead (as in my example with `dplyr`)

Comment: @blaugrana Now I update the code to `gsub(".*Bob.*","Bob",v)`, and hope this is what you want

Comment: Why do you have this question mark? (it doesn't hurt, but I don't see what it adds)

Comment: @prosoitos Sorry for typo, now it is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Using `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% mutate_all(~ gsub(".*Bob.*", "Bob", .))
```